# Search files by content using full boolean expressions

Tags: grep

Suppose I want to find all `*tex` files recursively from a given directory containing foo and bar but not doe. I am looking for something like helm-do-ag, but that doesn't seem to support the not operator. So is there anything like that which supports search queries with full boolean operations, i.e. something like: "find all tex files containing (apple AND orange) OR (banana and pear) not apricot".

Comment: Try this: `ag -L doe -G '\.tex$' --print0 | xargs -0 ag 'foo|bar'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the UNIX or GNU/Linux **`find`** command.  It supports Boolean operations.

In Emacs you can, for example, use command **`find-dired`**, which runs `find` and puts the set of found files in a Dired buffer.  You can then mark any number of them and then act on the marked files (e.g. `A` to search incrementally, `Q` to query-replace). (Emacs also has a `grep-find` command, at least for some platforms.)

**`find`** can search to any depth. It is an amazing command - practically a language unto itself.